# Toggle run script build phase in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, run-script

I have a run script build phase I have added to an Xcode project.

I want to be able to toggle this run script on when I want it to run and off when I don't.

Is this possible in Xcode and if so how can it be done?

Comment: What does it do? How do you want to control the on/off status? Can you add it as a different target?

Comment: You could move the script to a file, have the run script phase be a single line to execute the script in the file.

Then, just comment out the single line when you don't want it to run?

Comment: I decided to add it as a different target.  I set up an Aggregate target and added the run script there so that it would only run when building that target.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I used to write `exit` in the first line to toggle off the script and `#exit` to toggle on, just like this:

Turn off a script e.g. SwiftLint:

```
exit
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
  swiftlint
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

Turn on:

```
#exit
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
  swiftlint
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

You just have to modify 1 character whether exit is commented out or not.